# Produce a document and return a scalar with one XsltTransformer object?

Tags: saxon

I have a method that transforms an XML document into an HTML document.

```
    Processor saxProc = ...
    XsltTransformer trans = ...

    XdmNode source = saxProc.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
    trans.setInitialContextNode(source);
    Serializer out = saxProc.newSerializer(htmlFile);
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "html");
    trans.setDestination(out);
    trans.transform();
```

I now need this method to make available a new class member whose scalar value is the result of an XPATH expression executed upon the same source XML file.

Perhaps the best thing to do is create an additional [XsltTransformer](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltTransformer.html) to return the scalar value?

But after reading the doc for `setDestination` and [Destination](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Destination.html), I'm wondering, should I investigate the possibility of defining an additional destination that can receive the scalar value during the existing transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use XPath against your input document then use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathSelector.html by calling http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.html#newXPathCompiler--, http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathCompiler.html#compile-java.lang.String-, http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathExecutable.html#load-- on your Processor.